# Transform object literal to object containing paths?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'd like to take an object literal, and convert it to a new object where the new object keys are paths.

```
const obj = {
  test: {
    qwerty: 'text',
    abc: {
      testing: 123
    }
  }
}
```

To:

```
{
  'test.qwerty': 'text',
  'test.abc.testing': 123
}
```

I've been looking through the [lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4) but I can't see anything that might do this quickly.

The object literal could be any number of levels deep.

What's the best way to approach this..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if `lodash` has any built in function, but this is an approach using ES6 [`arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), optional parameters and recursive call:

```
const obj = {
  test: {
    qwerty: 'text',
    abc: {
      testing: 123
    }
  }
}


pathMyObject = (obj, prefix, newObj = {}) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach( key => {
        const value = obj[key];
        const newPrefix = (!prefix ? key : prefix + "." + key)
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            pathMyObject(value, newPrefix, newObj)
        } else {
            newObj[newPrefix] = value;
        }
    })
    return newObj
}

const path = pathMyObject(obj);

console.log(path);
/*
  { 
    'test.qwerty': 'text', 
    'test.abc.testing': 123 
  }
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive function using Lodash's [`reduce`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#reduce) function.

```js
const obj = {
  test: {
    qwerty: 'text',
    abc: {
      testing: 123
    }
  }
};

function toPaths(obj, path) {
  if (typeof obj !== 'object') { return { [path]: obj }; }
  return _.reduce(obj, (result, value, key) =>
    Object.assign({}, result, toPaths(value, path ? `${path}.${key}` : key))
  , {});
}

console.log(toPaths(obj));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

It's only slightly less verbose than the non-Lodash equivalent:

```js
const obj = {
  test: {
    qwerty: 'text',
    abc: {
      testing: 123
    }
  }
};

function toPaths(obj, path) {
  if (typeof obj !== 'object') { return { [path]: obj }; }
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((result, key) =>
    Object.assign({}, result, toPaths(obj[key], path ? `${path}.${key}` : key))
  , {});
}

console.log(toPaths(obj));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create recursive function to build object like this.

```js
const obj = {
  test: {
    qwerty: 'text',
    abc: {
      testing: 123
    }
  }
}

function toStrings(data) {
  var r = {}

  function inner(data, c) {
    for (var i in data) {
      if (typeof data[i] == 'object') inner(data[i], c + i + '.')
      else r[(c + i).replace(/\.$/, "")] = data[i]
    }
  }
  inner(data, '');
  return r;
}

console.log(toStrings(obj))
```